# How to migrate data from one Shopify store to another?

Tags: shopify, timber

I am the only developer on my small start up team. I got tasked with building an entirely new Shopify store platform from scratch (no Shopify starter theme) and I want to make sure I am not going to get fired for messing up. I have never built anything in a production environment.

I followed some online resources suggesting I start with the Timber framework to get started. After completely building out mobile, I was then told it was obsolete. I have been pretty much feeling around in the dark and implementing what knowledge I do have.

My team's current website theme is on *store.myshopify.com*. I have been building the new, highly-customized theme on *dev-store.myshopify.com*. **How do I transfer product reviews, store locator information, and other data from the old store over to the new store?**

Comment: You only want to move the data from old Shopify store to the new one? Shopify Admin Panel supports export/import products, orders using CSV file, but not for other data. I think this [**Shopify Migration Service**](https://next-cart.com/supported-carts/shopify/) is what you are looking for. The relationships between products to collections and orders are also preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a base theme, even if they say from scratch a base theme gives you most of the pages already coded and you can build on top of that.

You can start with the theme that comes with every shopify store or use the skeleton theme https://github.com/Shopify/skeleton-theme ( even though there is no sections implemented in the skeleton theme )

Once you install the theme on you can start modifying the important templates:

- index.liquid
- collection.liquid
- product.liquid
- cart.liquid
- page.liquid

The above templates are the most important ( if you have account registration than the account templates will be important as well )

If this is your first Shopify theme, don't go too crazy with the theme settings, stick only to the important bits. For example there is no need to allow the user to change how many products will be shown on the collection page or how many on the same row. You can hardcode a lot of the items and if the client want to change anything afterwards you can create an option in the theme settings panel.

Good resources to look into are:

- http://cheat.markdunkley.com/
- https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects

And don't use a framework like timber, you will complicated and loose yourself in the code.

Code the site as a simple HTML and convert it to a Shopify theme.

For example, the shop page in HTML will be:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="product">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

When you convert it to a liquid logic it will become:

```
<div class="products">
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        <div class="product">
            ....
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

So my recommendation is to start with the HTML phase, get an approval on that and then continue with the Shopify integration. You can use the Skeleton theme for reference or the launch theme that comes with each Shopify site.

If you have a complex Homepage with sliders and more than 1 section, I highly recommend to look into sections ( https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/introducing-sections-for-shopify-themes ) it will make your life a lot easier, rather than spamming multiply fields for each slide in the theme setting panel.

Hope that this information will be of use to you.

Comment: plus one on that cheat sheet.

Comment: THANK YOU! Unfortunately I've gone too far with Timber and don't have time to start from scratch once again. Next time...